# Is there a way to add an ad without squeezing the GLView?

Tags: java, android, adview

I am programming little games for myself and I am messing around with the google ads in my games. I am able to see them in game, but as the title says I have to arrange my layout that the GlView is ordered below the AdView, which causes the GLView(and my game) to get squeezed a bit.

Is there an other way to implement ads without getting the GLView resized?

Here is my layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#22baee">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4261152006862799/7796500146"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/glview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```